# Get users' applications from O365 waffle menu

Tags: azure, office365

After a user logs in to our system using his Microsoft school/organizational account, I'm trying to retrieve data about what applications are available to him.

Typically, one would see this information in the so-called "waffle menu" when entering, for example, portal.office.com as can be seen in the picture below.

After inspecting the website's requests, I found out that it's getting the data from https://portal.office.com/api/myapps/GetAllApp. However, to be able to access this resource, one needs to be logged in (i.e. have a session cookie) for office.com, but my application is using token-based authentication - I've registered my app in Azure AD, granted it permissions to access some services like MS Graph API and then I make requests with a token to access these.

The question is **can I get waffle menu information from some "Azure-friendly" app such as MS Graph API?** Alternatively, do you know about any other way of retrieving this information?

Thanks for any help or hints.

[image: The waffle menu]

Comment: Have you checked out the `assignedLicenses` property on users fetched from Microsoft Graph API? It could at least partially contain what you are looking for.

Comment: @juunas Yes, I have checked that, but do you perhaps mean `assignedPlans`? Because there I can see some of the apps (like SharePoint or Yammer), but I cannot see others such as Word/Excel. In the `assignedLicenses` I only see a `skuId` and an empty array for `disabledPlans`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something supported/available via [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/).

I'm also not aware of an API that exposes a user's waffle menu. I would suggest looking at [PowerShell for Office 365](http://powershell.office.com/). Given that this experience is isolated to the O365 Web UI, I suspect this isn't surfaced via an API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already one year old, but maybe someone else struggles to get the app information from O365.

As far as I've learned, there's no public API available to safely get the information. But with some workarounds, you can get the apps for the current logged on user from Office 365:

Here are the basic steps required to implement this:

- Create a (blank) SharePoint .aspx page

  - Add the `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />` tag to the page --> This will allow you to frame the page from any different environment
  - Add a script tag to the page and read the localStorage["SPSuiteLinksJson"] property --> In there, all relevant information for the user's apps are contained
  - Push the localStorage object (`window.top.postMessage(suiteLinks, "*");`) to the parent frame
- Upload the .aspx page to a library in SharePoint Online and grant read access for all users in your organisation
- Include an iFrame in a web application you control

  - Make sure to use a Smart Link to your SharePoint Online page (e.g. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&whr=<your adfs server>&wreply=https://<your tenant name>.sharepoint.com/pages/your-apps-proxy-page.aspx`)
  - Register a JavaScript event listener for the `message` event to receive the localStorage object from SharePoint Online

That's it, now you have the information about the apps for the current logged in user. Thank's to the Smart Link, the user doesn't need to log in to office.com beforehand to get the session cookie.

For more detailed information, so this blog post: https://sharepoint.cberger.ch/2018/03/09/office-365-app-launcher-on-prem/